# Extracting values stored in a 2D array of dictionaries with Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dictionary, for-loop

I have written a piece of code to determine the probability of getting a value Y when X dice are thrown. The equation I use contains a sum over range 0 up-to-and-including Y.

I want to plot the values on a grid (number of dice - sum of values) and have created a grid.

```
import scipy.special
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm as cm
import numpy as np
from numpy import exp,arange

def probability_of_sum(sum, dice, faces):
    # Give different names.
    X = sum
    Y = dice
    Z = faces

    # Calculations, calculations, calculations.
    # Dummy values.
    wanted_possibilities = 1
    total_possibilities = 2
    probability = wanted_possibilities/total_possibilities

    return {'wanted_possibilities':wanted_possibilities, 'total_possibilities':total_possibilities, 'probability':probability}


# Main part of the function.
# Consider 1 to 8 dice
# Get probabilities for lowest possible sum (8) to highest possible sum (48)

dice_range = np.linspace(1, 8, num=8)
value_range = np.linspace(1, 8*6, num=8*6)
X,Y = np.meshgrid( dice_range, value_range)

# Calculate value for each grid point separately using VECTORIZE.
value_prob = np.vectorize(probability_of_sum)( Y, X, 6)
```

The output of my function is now a 2D array of dictionaries (below are dummy values):

```
[[{'Wanted_possibilities': 0, 'total_possibilities':1, 'probability':0}
{'Wanted_possibilities': 1, 'total_possibilities':1, 'probability':1}]
 [{'Wanted_possibilities': 0, 'total_possibilities':2, 'probability':0}
{'Wanted_possibilities': 1, 'total_possibilities':2, 'probability':0.5}]
 [{'Wanted_possibilities': 0, 'total_possibilities':3, 'probability':0}
{'Wanted_possibilities': 1, 'total_possibilities':3, 'probability':0.33}]
 [{'Wanted_possibilities': 0, 'total_possibilities':4, 'probability':0}
{'Wanted_possibilities': 1, 'total_possibilities':4, 'probability':0.25}] ]
```

How do I continue from here to plot the output ('probability') as a 2D function of X and Y?

```
value_prob['probability']
```

gives me the error

> IndexError: only integers, slices(`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis(`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices.

I can access individual elements by using

```
(value_prob[1,1])['probability']
```

but then I would need a loop to plot the function. Is there a more general/powerful/cleaner way of accessing this?

EDIT: I would like to plot 'probability' against (dice, value).

Comment: Why are you using dictionaries to represent your data? You could have just added the values to the 2D array.

Comment: what are your `x-y` values headers? probability and total possibilities, or wanted possibilities and total possibilities?

Comment: @O.Suleiman - I opted to have dictionaries to have a clear distinction between the values that came out of the "probability_of_sum" function. How exactly would you add values to the array?

Comment: @Ajax1234 - the 2D plot would have x = 'dice', y = 'value' (the values used to construct the grid) and z = any of the three values in the result. Let's say 'probability'.

Comment: @AVS I meant you can add the values directly to the array of arrays and indicate what the value represents by its index in the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import itertools
import numpy as np
s = [[{'Wanted_possibilities': 0, 'total_possibilities':1, 'probability':0},
{'Wanted_possibilities': 1, 'total_possibilities':1, 'probability':1}],
 [{'Wanted_possibilities': 0, 'total_possibilities':2, 'probability':0},
{'Wanted_possibilities': 1, 'total_possibilities':2, 'probability':0.5}],
 [{'Wanted_possibilities': 0, 'total_possibilities':3, 'probability':0},
{'Wanted_possibilities': 1, 'total_possibilities':3, 'probability':0.33}],
 [{'Wanted_possibilities': 0, 'total_possibilities':4, 'probability':0},
{'Wanted_possibilities': 1, 'total_possibilities':4, 'probability':0.25}] ]
final_data = list(itertools.chain(*[[[i['Wanted_possibilities'], i['total_possibilities'], i['probability']] for i in b] for b in s]))
plt.bar(np.arange(len([i[-1] for i in final_data])), [i[0] for i in final_data], 0.60, yerr = [i[1] for i in final_data])
plt.ylabel('Probabilities')
plt.xticks(np.arange(len([i[-1] for i in final_data])), tuple(map(str, [i[-1] for i in final_data])))
plt.show()
```

[image]